# Multilinear Algebra, finding $z \wedge z.$

Tags: solution-verification, multilinear-algebra

> Define $A^k(V)$ to be the set of all alternating multilinear functions from $V^k \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the space $A^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$, does there exists $z\in A^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ such that $z \wedge z \neq 0$?

I played around with $$z\wedge z (v_1,\dots,v_4) = 4z(v_1,v_2)z(v_3,v_4) + 4z(v_1,v_3)z(v_2,v_4) + 4z(v_4,v_1)z(v_3,v_2).$$

It didn't provide me much insight to the answer. I mean you could let $v_i = v_j$, but that still doesn't lead me anywhere. So after playing around with some algebra, I concluded this map works.

$$z(v_1,v_2) = v_1^1v_2^2 - v_1^2v_2^1$$

It looks like some variation of the determinant $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
v_1^1 &v_2^1 \\ 
v_1^2 & v_2^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I verified that $z(v_1,v_2) = -z(v_1,v_2)$, but is that all or am I missing something big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $\{e_i\}$ a basis of $R^4$, and by $\{e^i\}$ the dual basis, $e^j(e_i)=\delta^j_i$. Then you can check that e.g. for $z=e^1\wedge e^2+e^3\wedge e^4$ we have $z\wedge z= 2 e^1\wedge e^2\wedge e^3 \wedge e^4\neq0$.

EDIT: So let me spell this out in more detail. First note that I have not used any particular properties of the $e^i$s, and since for any base of $V$ (finite dimensional) I can find a basis of $V^*$ defined by the relation above, so the example I gave is valid for *any* basis. Let us get the sign right. By definition of exterior product and apart an arbitrary conventional overall normalization factor we have
\begin{equation}
(z\wedge z)(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)=\sum_{\sigma}(-1)^\sigma z(v_{\sigma_1},v_{\sigma_2})z(v_{\sigma_3},v_{\sigma_4}),
\end{equation}
where $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3,\sigma_4 \}$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $(-1)^\sigma$ denotes the parity of the permutation and the sum is over all the permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. So a priori we expect $4!=24$ terms. By the antisymmetry property of forms, we can multiply by 4 and sum over the permutations with $\sigma_1<\sigma_2$, $\sigma_3<\sigma_4$, thus getting only $4\cdot3/2=6$ terms. You can write down them explicitly or note that taking e.g. $(v_1,v_2)$ as the argument of the first $z$ and $(v_3,v_4)$ as the argument of the second is the same taking first $(v_3,v_4)$ and then $(v_1,v_2)$ (this only holds because you are taking the product of $z$ with itself). Thus we van multiply by another factor of 2 and get only 3 terms:
\begin{equation}
(z\wedge z)(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)=8[(-1)^{\sigma} z(v_1,v_2)z(v_3,v_4)+(-1)^\tau z(v_1,v_3)z(v_2,v_4)+(-1)^\rho z(v_1,v_4)z(v_2,v_3)],
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is the permutation $\{1,2,3,4\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4\}$ which is clearly even, $\tau$ is the permutation $\{1,2,3,4\}\rightarrow \{1,3,2,4\}$ which is odd and $\rho$ is the permutation $\{1,2,3,4\}\rightarrow \{1,4,2,3\}$ which is even. Therefore we finally have
\begin{equation}
(z\wedge z)(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)=8[z(v_1,v_2)z(v_3,v_4)- z(v_1,v_3)z(v_2,v_4)+ z(v_1,v_4)z(v_2,v_3)].
\end{equation}

> More generally, since $e^i\wedge e^i=0$, if you want a form wedge itself to be non-zero, it has to be a sum of more than one (non-zero) term (that is not sufficient, e. g. if $z=e^1\wedge e^2+ e^1\wedge e^3 $ then $z\wedge z=0$). Actually it also needs to be of even degree as an odd form wedge itself is necessarily zero, can you see why?

Comment: That's an answer I found as well, but am I wrong? Because my map is really simple…I mean your example suggests a generalization, which is nice as well.

Comment: I think that with my notation your map is $z=e^1\wedge e^2$ since $e^1\wedge e^2(v_1,v_2)= v_1^1 v_2^2-v^1_2v^2_1$. But then $z\wedge z=0$ so I think your $z$ is not what you were looking for.

Comment: is there a mistake in my expansion then? Because my sum isn't $0$...

Comment: Yes, in your sum the second term should come with a minus sign.

Comment: My friend got $2z(v_1,v_2)z(v_3,v_4) - 4z(v_1,v_3)z(v_2,v_4)$, I think he is missing a term. Am I missing a term?

Comment: Because according to this physicist, http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~tim/open/pfaff/pfaff.pdf, I am over counting and I can't figure out why I am over counting.

Comment: And according to my math, $4C2 = 6$, but since I can permutation the entire set, I get 12 terms, which is what I got.

Comment: No you aren't missing a term, and is sort of intuitive that the answer should contain the $v_i$ in all possible combinations with the same coefficient. You have got the wrong sign for the 2nd term. Remember that you need to consider the parity pf the permutation in the definition of exterior product. I am going to sleep now, sorry. Good luck!

Comment: when you are a awake; are you forcing to define your dual basis for only standard basis?

Comment: So as far as I can tell (1) The output of $z$ is still going to be the determinant of a permutation matrix, (2)comparing my result with yours, my permutation coefficients (with 4s) is incorrect. How are you getting the $8$ in front? I thought you said we agreed that plugging in $(v_3,v_4)$ first and then $(v_1,v_2)$ in that order is the same as the reverse (and that's what i got, so I didn't count them, is that the mistake? Because I thought I would be double counting)

Comment: (1) yes. (2)it gives the same value, but that does not mean you should not count it (and it would not give you the same if you were calculating $z\wedge x$ with $x\neq z$)!

Comment: I think I understand how you were defining your dual basis now. My brain is so used to thinking that $e_i$ is the vector whose component is $1$ in the ith slot and $0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you're familiar with the terminology of differential forms, try computing $\omega \wedge \omega$ where: $$\omega = x  \ dx \wedge dy + y \ dz \wedge dw$$

Comment: I was going to do that too, but I wanted to come up with a more "fundamental" answer, free of differentials.

Comment: Those aren't differentials; they're just a different notation (and, quite common) notation for basis covectors.

Comment: Well.. if $x_i: \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R$ are the coordinate functions for $\Bbb R^4$, then fixed $p \in \Bbb R^4$, $(dx_i)_p: T_p\Bbb R^4 \to T_{x_i(p)}\Bbb R$ is the differential of $x_i$ at $p$. The map $dx_i$, which maps $p$ to $(dx_i)_p$ is called a $1-$form.

Comment: I am reading this from a book that deals with "application in differential forms", so it's probably written for a physicist.

Comment: Do Carmo's Differential Forms and Applications, and Barrett O'Neill's Elementary Differential Geometry are nice books to take a look at, for this subject.

Comment: I am reading "A geometric approach to differential forms", and I am just randomly finding "mathy" problems along the way as I am doing applications.

Comment: Who's the author? I might as well take a look too (:

Comment: @IvoTerek, David Bachman. But this question, I found it online. I've done enough applications of the wedge product, so I am trying out theoretical problems.

Comment: My brain is really glitching tonight, I think your form sends elements in $R^4 \to R^1$

Comment: No. The form $dx_i$ takes a point $p \in \Bbb R^4$ to a linear functional $(dx_i)_p$ in $(T_p\Bbb R^4)^*$. Ok?

Comment: @IvoTerek, ah nvm, you have $dx \wedge dy$, which takes two vectors from $\mathbb{R}^4$, so it is okay. Your final result $\omega \wedge \omega = 2xy dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dw$. This takes $4$ vectors and sends them to the 4 x4 determinant right? And By just finding any linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, it will do the job of showing $\omega \wedge \omega \neq 0$? Because my computation shows that it *can* equal to $0$.

Comment: That is correct, $\omega \wedge \omega$ will send $4$ vectors to the $4 \times 4$ determinant. When I said that $\omega \wedge \omega$ could not be zero, I meant that it is not identically zero. You can find linearly independent vectors such that the wedge product vanishes at them, I suppose.

Comment: Actually this just made me realize that (probably so obvious you think I am dumb for mentioning it…) each $dx_i$ is a $1$ form. As your comment above (and above) said.

Comment: @IvoTerek, Um, if the vectors are linearly independent, the determinant can't be $0$…it only works if they linearly dependent, which subtlety appeals to the definition of an alternating form.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make myself clear. The determinant can't be zero, but $\omega \wedge \omega$ can. Notice that $\omega \wedge \omega$ is a non identically zero $4$-form. If you choose, say, $p = (0,0,1,1)$, then $(\omega \wedge \omega)_p$ is the null functional. So you can have linearly independent vectors $(v^i)_{i = 1}^4$ and $$(\omega \wedge \omega)_p(v^1,v^2,v^3,v^4) = 2 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 \cdot (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \wedge dw)_p(v^1,v^2,v^3,v^4) = 0.$$